Decomposition of functions into infinite polynomials
There are many ways of decomposing a function $f(x)$, defined on a compact subest $[a,b]$ as a sum of infinite polynomial terms. My question is the following: let's say that we choose a function that has both a Taylor series on $[a,b]$ and a Legendre expansion on $[a,b]$. If we expand all the Legendre polynomials, such that we can see the coefficient of every power of $x$, is it true that the two polynomials will math? i.e. that their coefficients are the same?
Because, thinking about it logically if two power series converge to a function on a given interval then they should be the same, however these two expansions are based on different principles, so I'm not sure that they would match.
